# Why is the second element being printed in map?

Tags: c++

In the below code, why element 2 is being returned instead of element 1 when begin() is used ? Could somebody please explain this ?

```
int main()
{
    map <string, int> name;

    // Adding the contents into map

    name["David"]   = 1;
    name["Charlie"] = 2;
    name["Robert"]  = 3;

     map<string, int>::iterator i1 =name.begin(); 

        cout << "The first element is : " << (*i1).first << "The second     
    element is "<<(*i1).second<<endl;

    }
```

In the output I am getting as

The first element is : Charlie The second element is 2

Comment: Because [std::map](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map) is a sorted container.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you add items to the `map`, they automatically get sorted by keys. This means that the map stores your item by the alphabetical order of the key. In that case, `Charlie` gets first spot, then `David` and finally `Robert`.

Should you change `Charlie` for `John`, then `David` would be stored first. I'm not entirely sure of what you intend to do with this, but it would seem that your numbers should be your keys instead

Answer (score 1):

`std::map` is a sorted container. The values which get sorted are of type `std::pair< std::string, int >`. So the first item is the pair `{"Charlie", 2}`. It happens that the members of `pair` are named `first` and `second`.

So `std::pair< std::string, int >{"Charlie", 2}.first` is `"Charlie"`, and
 `std::pair< std::string, int >{"Charlie", 2}.second` is `2`.

`first` and `second` are not referring to the sorted sequence of the `map`.